# Image not being displayed in my mvc application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an image tag among a table of several other tds

```
<table class="MyClass">
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ShopName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ShopName, new { @class = "form-control", id = "myid1", @readonly = true, @Enabled = "False" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ShopName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter ShopName", id = "myid2", @maxlength = "200" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ShopName)
        </td>
        <td class="myclass2" rowspan="3">
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cardDialog" href="#"><img src="~/Content/dist/img/card.svg" id="imgId"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the `document.ready` i am using the model property `ImagePath` to assign the img src to the image id `imgId`

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    var imgpth = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ImagePath));
    $('#imgId').attr('src',imgpth);
});
```

I am getting the path from the database ,

```
imgpth:`D:\\Myproject\\ResponseImages\\1005\\100526122016151240_1005_0_261216_15_39_53.JPEG`
```

Let me tell you that the path above is in a different folder from my current application.

i.e. the application running on the server is in folder `D:\\MVCProject\\...`

where as the images are in the folder `D:\\Myproject\\...`

But it is not displaying the image, rather it is displaying the default image that is assigned to the image control itself.

**EDIT 1**

This is my controller code where i am getting the path from,

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ResponseObj = new ModelResponseDetails();
    //Some other controls data
    ResponseObj.ShopName=ds.Tables[18].Rows[0]["ShopName"].ToString();
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ResponseObj.ImagePath = ds.Tables[18].Rows[0]["ImagePath"].ToString();
    return View(ResponseObj);
}
```

and 
ds.Tables[18].Rows[0]["ImagePath"].ToString() has `D:\Myproject\ResponseImages\1005\100526122016151240_1005_0_261216_15_39_53.JPEG`
Can some one tell if there is something wrong with my approach, either the way the path is being assigned to the `imgpth` variable or the jquery code etc??

Comment: How are you setting the value of `ImagePath` in your GET method (you should be using `Server.MapPath()`)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke i am setting the value of ImagePath in the ActionMethod of the controller.

Comment: Yes I know - but I asked **how**

Comment: @StephenMuecke ImagePath is set when the view is being rendered with is model properties. I have edited my question accordingly, you can go through it.

Comment: You need to be storing your image path using `Server.MapPath()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I did not completely get you, are you saying that i have to be saving the path in the database using Server.MapPath() or should i be using Server.MapPath while reading it from the database while I assign to the image src

Comment: I have just checked  my code where i am storing the path into the database. And this is what i found                                                                  var TempPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(TempFolder);

Comment: In that case, you should be able to use `var imgpth = "@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)";`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok, so now how do i access a different folder in the same directory where my application folder exists. I gave the scenario in my question above. Please bear with me if i feel too stupid to ask such question.

Comment: And also when i used var imgpth = "@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)"; The actual path D:\MyProject\ResponseImages\1005\100526122016151240_1005_0_261216_15_39_53.JPEG is being converted into D:MyProjectResponseImages@5@526122016151240_1005_0_261216_15_39_53.JPEG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `var imgpth = "@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)"`